# Slow WiFi internet speed but OK on LAN

Tags: wireless-networking, performance

The issue that I am having is that when I perform an Ookla internet speed test from any of my WiFi devices I get slow download speed.

The setup:

```
                A                    Router-----Cable Modem--------ISP
                |                     |         Rated 100 down
1000mbs LAN ----+------+--------------+----
                       |
                      WiFi
                     /   \
                    /     \
                   B       C
                801.n    801.ac
```

Here are a few tests I performed:

| Test | Data Rate | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ookla internet speed test from A | 110mbs | great! |
| Ookla internet speed test from B | 24mbs | SLOW ! |
| Ookla internet speed test from C | 24mbs | SLOW ! |
| Copy 800MByte file from A to B | 75mbs | Expected |
| Copy 800MByte file from B to A | 88mbs | Expected |
| Copy 800MByte file from A to C | 95mbs | Expected |

None of the hardware was altered in any way between these tests (no config changes or reboots).
All systems are Windows 10 Pro.
WiFi device is Netgear WAC510 - Insight Managed Smart Cloud Access Point.
Router is Linksys LRT214 Gigabit VPN Router.

So the question is: Why is the WiFi link so slow from B and C to the ISP?

Comment: Did you perhaps mistakenly list the last row as “expected” when it should’ve been “slow”? Because I regularly got 500 MBit/s over 2×2 11ac. I also suggest you use unambiguous units (Mbyte/s, Mbit/s).

Comment: mbs is mega-bits-per-second.

Comment: I would try to reconfigure your Wifi. Make sure 5GHz Wifi is activated and usable by the Wifi client. Also limit the used Wifi channel to 20MHz instead of extra-large channels of 80 or even 160MHz. Theoretically more fused frequencies mean more speed, but more frequencies also have a higher chance of disturbances by other Wifis or radio based systems around you. So effectively a 20MHz Wifi can be faster that one with 160MHz.

Comment: How would that change explain (or fix) the B-A vs B-ISP difference?  The tests demonstrate that the B-WiFi link can achieve ~80mbs.

Comment: The channel is  80mhz wide.  I am in a pretty remote location. The WiFi analyzer shows no other APs on the 4 channels being used.

Comment: I have been thinking about "Did you perhaps mistakenly list the last row as “expected” when it should’ve been “slow”? Because I regularly got 500 MBit/s over 2×2 11ac. I also suggest you use unambiguous units (Mbyte/s, Mbit/s). – Daniel B yesterday".  The WiFi device I have is raw rate of 877mbs and I am only seeing ~100mbs at best when wokring intra-lan. This really IS slow for. I would think I should be seeing ~300mbs (or better).  

I have ordered a new WiFi device, a TP-Link EAP620, to see how that does and if my original problem goes away. It should be here on 8/16. Keep you posted,

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's the deal...

I obtained a different WiFi Access Point and while I was hooking it up I just started with a  "basic" setup and got 100Mbps download speed. Great!  Then I added my two other VLANs to it and the speed dropped back to exactly the same values I had seen with the old AP. After some exploration I discovered that if I connect either of them to my smart-switches with TAGGED ports (required for VLAN) then the performance drops from 100Mbs to 20MBs.

My "solution," at least for now, is to not use the VLAN support and connect the AP to the smart-switch over on an UNTAGGED port with just a single SSID. I'll work out why this is such an issue. The Router that I am using is a Linksys LRT214 and the smart switches are Netgear GS108E. The problem is with either the Router or the Switch and I'll need to fiddle around with the network configuration to isolate which is the issue.

My VLAN configuration uses 3 smart-switches and it all seems to work OK except for this case. If there are any 802.1Q wizards out there that "see" the problem let me know.

My current config that's relevant to this this is:

```
AP--->GS108E--->Router--->WAN
```

So my first test will be this:

```
AP--->Router--->WAN
```

to see if that fixes it. If so, then the problem was with the GS108E. If that doesn't fix it then the issue is with the LRT214 or the 802.1Q protocol is too slow for this (which I doubt).

We'll see.